# What is the purpose of sqlbulkcopy's useinternaltransaction property?

Tags: sql-server, oracle, ado.net, bulkcopy

I'm just testing my PowerShellScript to do bulkcopy of multiple tables between sql-server and oracle Databases.
When the destination is Oracle, than I can monitor the progress by by executing

**select count(*) from Mytable**

the single batchsize chunkss individual committed.

Using a sql-server destination, there seems to be a single transaction. Which was rolledback due to network error at first trial. The second is still in progress. Will the use of internal transaction commit the individual chunks?

The use of bulkcopy seems a bit of an all or nothing, if it fails you can restart from the beginning.

```
$source = 'ora'
$dest = 'sql'

$SourceConnectionString_sql      = "Data Source=localhost;Initial Catalog=MySQLDatabase;Integrated Security=True"
$SourceConnectionString_ora      = "Data Source=MyOracleDatabase;User ID=MyUser;Password=MyPassword"

$DestinationConnectionString_sql = "Data Source=localhost;Initial Catalog=MySqleDatabase2;Integrated Security=True"
$DestinationConnectionString_ora = "Data Source=MyOracleDatabase2;User ID=MyUser;Password=MyPassword"


# -----------------------------------------------------------------------------

$SQL_Select_TABLES = "SELECT name FROM sys.Tables ORDER BY 1"
$SQL_Select_TABLES = "SELECT Top 1 name FROM sys.Tables"

$ORA_Select_TABLES = "SELECT TABLE_NAME Name FROM user_tables ORDER BY 1"
$ORA_Select_TABLES = "SELECT TABLE_NAME Name FROM user_tables where ROWNUM = 1"

$notifyAfter = 1000
# -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
if ($ora_dll -eq $null)
{
    $ora_dll = [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Oracle.DataAccess") 
}

$global:start = get-date
$notifyFunction={ 
    $dauer = [int]((get-date) - $global:start).TotalMilliseconds / 1000
    Write-Host "$tableName $($args[1].RowsCopied) $dauer"
    } 

if ($dest -eq 'sql')
{
    $bulkCopy = new-object ("Data.SqlClient.SqlBulkCopy") $DestinationConnectionString_sql
}
else
{
    $bulkCopy = new-object ("Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleBulkCopy") $DestinationConnectionString_ora
}


$bulkCopy.BatchSize = 50000
$bulkCopy.BulkCopyTimeout=10000000
if ($notifyAfter -gt 0){
    $bulkCopy.NotifyAfter=$notifyafter
    if ($dest -eq 'sql')
    {
       $bulkCopy.Add_SQlRowscopied($notifyFunction)
    }
    else
    {
       $bulkCopy.Add_OracleRowscopied($notifyFunction)
    }

}

if ($source -eq 'sql')
{
    $sourceConnection  = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SQLConnection($SourceConnectionString_sql)
    $sourceConnection.open()

    $commandSourceData  = New-Object system.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand($SQL_Select_TABLES, $sourceConnection)
    $da = New-Object system.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter($commandSourceData)
    $dt = New-Object system.Data.datatable
    [void]$da.fill($dt)
}
else
{
    $sourceConnection  = New-Object Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleConnection($SourceConnectionString_ora)
    $sourceConnection.open()

    $commandSourceData  = New-Object Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleCommand($Ora_Select_TABLES, $sourceConnection)
    $da = New-Object Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleDataAdapter($commandSourceData)
    $dt = New-Object system.Data.datatable
    [void]$da.fill($dt)
}

foreach ($table in $dt)
{
    $tablename  = $table.name
    $Tablename
    try
    {
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM $tableName"
        if ($source -eq 'sql')
        {
            $commandSourceData  = New-Object system.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand($sql,$sourceConnection)
        }
        else
        {
            $commandSourceData  = New-Object Oracle.DataAccess.Client.oracleCommand($sql,$sourceConnection)
        }
        $reader = $commandSourceData.ExecuteReader()
        $bulkCopy.DestinationTableName = $tableName
        $bulkCopy.WriteToServer($reader)
    }
    catch
    {
        $ex = $_.Exception
        Write-Host "Write-DataTable$($connectionName):$ex.Message"
    }
    finally
    {
        $reader.close()
    }
}
$sourceConnection.close()
$bulkCopy.close()

((get-date) - $start).TotalSeconds
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand you correctly:

- You'd use [BatchSize](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlbulkcopy.batchsize.aspx) to break the load into chunks eg 10k rows
- [UseInternalTransaction](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlbulkcopyoptions.aspx) determines if each batch is a transaction

So:

- BatchSize = 0 -> UseInternalTransaction is irrelevant
- BatchSize > 0 -> Apply UseInternalTransaction is specified

FYI, to monitor a SQL Server load in a non-blocking fashion

```
select count(*) from Mytable WITH (nolock)
```

Comment: Thanks for the (nolock) hint. Setting UseInternalTransaction works as expected, but since I have no clear way to continue a broken transmission, it seems to be best to work with BatchSize = 0.